# Color scheme in spark web UI

Tags: apache-spark

What does the blue zone represent? I can understand the green zone represents the computing time. By going from legend, the blue zone should represent scheduler delay.However, the numbers do not match as mentioned schedular delay is negligible to the executor time. So, what does it means?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler is the part of the master that constructs the DAG of stages and tasks and interacts with the cluster to distribute them in the most efficient way it can. Scheduler Delay is the overhead of how long it takes to ship tasks to the executors and get the results back.

This is how it is calculated in the most recent [branch](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/jobs/StagePage.scala):

```
private[ui] def getSchedulerDelay(
      info: TaskInfo, metrics: TaskMetricsUIData, currentTime: Long): Long = {
    if (info.finished) {
      val totalExecutionTime = info.finishTime - info.launchTime
      val executorOverhead = (metrics.executorDeserializeTime +
        metrics.resultSerializationTime)
      math.max(
        0,
        totalExecutionTime - metrics.executorRunTime - executorOverhead -
          getGettingResultTime(info, currentTime))
    } else {
      // The task is still running and the metrics like executorRunTime are not available.
      0L
    }
}
```